# python to rig my maya character- error: Parent of end effector must be a joint

Tags: python, maya

I'm using code to rig my character in maya- the IK FK arm is giving me problems.

error "line 72: Parent of end effector must be a joint."
Below is line 72.

```
handle, effector = cmds.ikHandle(sj=joints[0], ee=joints[-1], sol="ikRPsolver")  #sj is start joint, ee is end effector
cmds.parent(handle, ikctrl)
```

this is snippets from the code further down. What am I doing wrong? Where am I causing this issue?

```
def ikfkchain(name, side, parent, joints, fktemplate, iktemplate, pvtemplate, fkcolor, ikcolor):
rig_group = cmds.createNode("transform", n="{0}_{1}_GRP".format(side, name))   #making a group for the arm rig
if parent:
    cmds.parent(rig_group, parent)


# duplicate chains

ik_driver_group = cmds.createNode("transform", n="{0}_{1}IkRig_GRP".format(side, name))
cmds.parent(ik_driver_group, rig_group)       


fk_joints = duplicate_chain(joints, rig_group, "_JNT", "Fk_JNT")
ik_joints = duplicate_chain(joints, rig_group, "_JNT", "Ik_JNT")
ik_driver_joints = duplicate_chain(joints, ik_driver_group, "_JNT", "IkDriver_JNT")
blend_joints = duplicate_chain(joints, rig_group, "_JNT", "Blend_JNT")

#connect blend chain

for ikjnt, fkjnt, bjnt in zip(ik_joints, fk_joints, blend_joints):
    for transformation in ["translate", "rotate", "scale"]:
        blc = cmds.createNode("blendColors", n=bjnt.replace("_JNT", "{0}_BLC".format(transformation.capitalize())))
        cmds.connectAttr("{0}.{1}".format(ikjnt, transformation), "{0}.color1".format(blc))
        cmds.connectAttr("{0}.{1}".format(fkjnt, transformation), "{0}.color2".format(blc))
        cmds.connectAttr("{0}.output".format(blc), "{0}.{1}".format(bjnt, transformation))
       #blender

for ikdjnt, ikjnt in zip(ik_driver_joints, ik_joints):
    cmds.pointConstraint(ikdjnt, ikjnt)
    cmds.orientConstraint(ikdjnt, ikjnt)
    cmds.scaleConstraint(ikdjnt, ikjnt)


 #rig
fkcontrols = fkchain(rig_group, fk_joints, fktemplate, fkcolor)
ikctrl, pvctrl = ikchain(name, side, rig_group, ik_driver_joints, iktemplate, pvtemplate, ikcolor)
```

def duplicate_chain(joints, parent, replace_what, replace_with):
new_joints = []
new_joints_parent = parent

```
for jnt in joints:
    new_jnt = cmds.duplicate(jnt, n=jnt.replace(replace_what, replace_with), po=True)[0]
    if new_joints_parent:
        cmds.parent(new_jnt, new_joints_parent)


    new_joints_parent = new_jnt 
    new_joints.append(new_jnt)

    return new_joints
```

Comment: With only a snippet it it hard to see what's happening. Did you check the content of `joints[-1]` and it's parent? If the error message is correct, the parent should be something else but a joint.

Comment: I believe this might be related to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71109858/why-is-duplicating-joints-by-code-not-working) where you are returning a list of one joint.